# Using stored procedures with parameterized queries. What is the meaning of it?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, parameterized-query

Why we use parameterized queries? Because we tell it what type of parameter should it accept (integer, string, ....).

```
prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ?")
bind_param("i", $id)  //only accepts integer
```

On the other hand we already telling a stored procedure what type of input should it accept

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select(IN id INT) //only int as id
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE id =id;
END //
```

So what is the meaning writing a parameterized query after calling a stored procedure?

**NOTE:** Using mysql trying to use stored procedures. Not sure if I should delete my before parameterized queries.

Comment: why something like that depens on dbms? please explain

Comment: this question's reason is clear as day. I am asking if its necessary or not.  Idk how to be more specific. there is a group who clicks "on hold" whenever they can't tell something about question. Which is SoF's biggest problem

Answer (score 1):

NO, your first shown form is a `DYNAMIC QUERY` or `prepared query`

```
prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id= ?")
bind_param("i", $id)  //only accepts integer
```

So with `bind_param` you are dynamically binding the parameter value with the `$id` variable.

If you are calling the stored procedure with passing the id parameter then there is no need of that dynamic query building.